# Require comments on close or delete votes on heavily-upvoted questions

Tags: feature-request, comments, closed-questions, historical-lock

A few years ago, [I asked a question about the differences between two competing Python libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696884/python-nose-vs-unittest).  The answer to the question, which detailed 10 or so differences received 84 upvotes along with the question.  Unfortunately, the question was closed without explanation and is now on track to being deleted without explanation.

Also, someone since posted a heavily-upvoted comment saying that the question was very constructive and criticizing its closing.  Instead of replying to the comment, a moderator decided to delete that comment.  This is indefensibly unprofessional.

**Given the *unique factual rather than discussional* answer, would most people consider the question not to be constructive?**

**What is the point of deleting questions versus closing them?  Even if it's not what's happening, deleting comes across as eliminating a magnet for moderator criticism.  How can that image be prevented?**

Heavily upvoted questions have attracted a lot of attention and are demonstrably useful to many people.  When these questions are closed or deleted, it incites criticism of moderation.  This can be avoided by having the close-voters explain their reasoning in comments. It is not enough to explain the site rules somewhere because it's not obvious to everyone how the site rules apply to such questions.  Yes, it is more work for overworked moderators, but there is always a balance between doing a good job and making it clear to people that you are doing a good job.  It also establishes trust.

Should there be a requirement to explain why a particular question is voted to be closed or deleted if the question has a given number of upvotes?

Comment: There *was* an explanation: *closed as not constructive*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Please read my question fully :)

Comment: Please don't confuse popularity (votes) with suitability to the Stack Overflow model. Just because something receives a lot of votes doesn't make it auto-worthy of extra protection.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: "It is not enough to explain the site rules somewhere because it's not obvious to everyone how the site rules apply to such questions."

Comment: That's what we have Meta for. You can come here and ask for clarifications. Let's not complicate the system more, shall we?

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Okay.  This is what I'm doing. Have I made a mistake with using meta?  Is there a reason why my question is being downvoted?

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on Meta are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. You posted a feature-request, people disagree with the request.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah, ok.

Comment: A moderator did not delete it, contrary to your statement above, he merely closed it.

Comment: @servy: I didn't say that a moderator deleted the question :)

Comment: @NeilG And now you've attracted a lot of attention on an off-topic closed question.  The delete votes are piling up because of this.

Comment: @bluefeet: I am trying to understand StackOverflow better.  Is this the wrong way to do that?

Comment: @NeilG You claimed that a moderator decided to delete it.  He did not delete it.  He closed it.  See the revision history for this question.

Comment: @servy:  That paragraph is talking about a deleted comment.  Comments are deleted not closed, right?

Comment: @NeilG Then say that; in context it's ambiguous.

Comment: @Servy:  The subject of the paragraph is clear to me: "Also, someone since posted a heavily-upvoted **comment**…"  I thought bolding it would be insulting :)

Comment: @NeilG Just to put your mind as ease the "heavily upvoted comment" was flagged by another user as not constructive.  During the review of the flags the comment was deleted.  Comments are also considered an after-thought and you shouldn't expect them to stick around permanently even if they are upvoted.

Comment: @bluefeet: Yes, I didn't like the tone of the comment either.  What I am pointing out is that when you are faced with that kind of situation, deleting looks bad to the dozen-or-so people who upvoted the comment.  It looks like stifling criticism, which only attracts ire.  Even if the comment is deleted, it should have been replaced with an explanation — just like you would do in a professional environment.

Comment: @bluefeet:  That's a fine argument.  What I'm suggesting to you is that just like at work, there's a balance between doing good work and making it clear that you're doing good work.  You fill in progress reports, right?  Progress reports are similarly not "work" so much as they are "making it clear that you're doing work".  (I don't like doing progress reports either.)

Comment: @NeilG So you really expect moderators to comment on everything that we do?

Comment: @NeilG The best way to keep us accountable is to bring up issues on meta.  One particular thing I like is to make all moderator actions public.  (I think I suggested it on meta a few years ago). I think all moderator actions should be public. I'm ok with that. I also think *All* user moderation type action should be public. Any user: re-open? Public. Close? public. Vote to delete? Public. Vote to undelete? Public.

Comment: "What is the point of deleting questions versus closing them?" -- broken windows theory.

Comment: @bluefeet: I think it's a good idea from a professional standpoint for deletion of highly-upvoted things — for some threshold of "highly-upvoted" that is not onerous for you, while preventing bad feelings from developing.  I'm not suggesting this for any personal reason, but because I think that the site would benefit from mitigating bad blood.

Comment: @Wooble: Then why bother having close at all?

Comment: @NeilG I don't think you truly understand how much work the mods do and adding a comment to everything would increase that substantially.  If you have an issue with the moderating of the site you should bring it to meta.

Comment: @NeilG: That's a good point. I'll heartily support your feature-request to just delete "On Hold" questions after 3 days instead of changing them to "Closed"

Comment: @bluefeet:  I am suggesting a threshold whereby the number of moderator actions requiring comment would be small enough that wouldn't be a burden.  And I am suggesting this not to increase your work, but to increase the (social) credit you get for your work.  Instead of seeing my suggestion as impinging on time that could be spent closing and deleting things, I hope that you see it as something that is intrinsically beneficial.

Comment: @Wooble: Maybe you should add a suggestion to meta?  I am curious how it would be received.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for

Comment: @gnat There is no historical lock on this question, nor do I see any compelling reason to apply one.  It is not a question that is of *enormous* value that absolutely must not be deleted.  Given the state that it's currently in (very out of date) it doesn't even appear to be of marginal value, let alone enormous value.

Comment: @Servy no problem. Historical lock is always an option to consider when discussing questions like this; criteria to decide whether the question deserves it are outlined in the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) referred in my prior comment. If a particular question fails to meet these criteria, so be it

Answer (score 19):

Oddly enough, I'm the moderator that closed your question (I happened upon it because I was doing Python work at the time).

Your question was closed because it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow. This has nothing to do with whether or not it's a popular or good question.  A question being open indicates it's a good fit for Stack Overflow, a question having votes indicates it's a popular (or good) question.  Those two states are orthogonal to each other.

It's a great question. Let's get that out of the way.

But, what would the end state to such a question look like? How would we determine an objectively correct answer?

You could potentially have dozens of answers, each with a different advantage and disadvantage. Which answer would be objectively correct?

Stack Overflow doesn't do well when the answers are based on "In my Opinion", nor does it do well when there's just a list of things.  Part of the utility in a Stack Overflow question is that it is easily googleable, and that it solves a problem the googler has.  In this case, "Advantages and Disadvantages" are not a problem. "I can't get Nose to run because *X*" is a problem.

Also, the question doesn't really have a good answer.  It had two years to collect some good content, but it failed to do so in two years. That also means that there's not much to lose if the question is deleted.

If you want the question to stay around, put some effort in making the answer good enough that we wouldn't want the question deleted. As it stands, there's not really a reason to keep the question around.

To answer the rest of your rather bold questions:

> Given the unique factual rather than discussional answer, would most people consider the question not to be constructive?

It's opinion based; and a point in time view of each library from one user's perspective. While parts of the answer are factually correct; other parts are that user's *opinion*.

> What is the point of deleting questions versus closing them?

It's not really a 'vs' thing. It's closing *can lead to* deletion (not always, though).

We close questions because they are not a good fit for Stack Overflow (for a multitude of reasons).

We delete questions because they are not a good fit *and* they do not contain any content that we should keep around. Content that expands the useful repository of programmer knowledge.

> Even if it's not what's happening, deleting comes across as eliminating a magnet for moderator criticism. How can that image be prevented?

Moderators delete questions.  If we do something you think is incorrect, bring it up on Meta. In this case, although I could have deleted your question, *I chose not to*. I chose to leave that option to the community, because I don't  think it's crystal clear that it should be deleted.  In this case, I'm deferring to the community.  Sometimes I don't, because of established practice. In this case I did.

That's normal for a community-elected moderator. We were elected to use our best judgement in carrying out moderator duties across Stack Overflow.  We really are glorified janitors.

> Should there be a requirement to explain why a particular question is voted to be closed or deleted if the question has a given number of upvotes?

I try really hard to leave comments when I close a question unilaterily. I try to go above and beyond. I don't always do this, and I haven't always done it.  In this case, I chose not to, but I was also a 'young' moderator then.  As far as a requirement, no there shouldn't.  As I explained earlier, a questions votes have no bearing on whether it belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not to mention that the answer is already outdated because both `unittest` and `nose` have evolved since then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Actually, that's addressed in the comments to the answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Thanks for taking the time to answer my meta question.  Would you be able to answer all of my (bolded) questions?

Comment: @NeilG: Exactly; comments are needed to keep the answer from becoming irrelevant altogether. But noone is maintaining the answer *itself*.