# What should be done about this specific famous controversial question asking when to use Node.js?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

The following question has gathered more than 2.000 upvotes, almost 300.000 views and 17 answers. Here's the gist of it:

> #### [How to decide when to use Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5062614/4174897)
>
> *(... Description of Node.JS ...)*
>
> Considering that Node.js can be run almost out-of-the-box on Amazon's EC2 instances, I am trying to understand what type of problems require Node.js as opposed to any of the mighty kings out there like PHP, Python and Ruby. I understand that it really depends on the expertise one has on a language, but my question falls more into the general category of: When to use a particular framework and what type of problems is it particularly suited for?

This question has a [rough history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5062614/revisions):

- Closed by then-diamond Andrew Barber in 2013, it was reopened a couple days later by Shog9♦;
- Closed by five voters in 2014, it was reopened by Adam Lear♦ the next day;
- Closed by five voters in 2015, it was reopened by five voters a few weeks ago;
- Closed by five voters some time ago, it was reopened by five voters after this Meta post;
- Closed by five voters a couple days ago, it was reopened hours later;
- It has now been closed again by five voters.

This question went through the CV queue quite a few times (invalidated reviews excluded):

- [06 May 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2054905) -> Close x 0 | **Leave Open** x 3
- [13 May 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2099861) -> Close x 0 | **Leave Open** x 3
- [23 Aug 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2777728) -> Close x 0 | **Leave Open** x 3
- [05 Feb 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3983998) -> **Close** x 4 | Leave Open x 1
- [12 Jun 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5044693) -> Close x 0 | **Leave Open** x 3
- [06 Feb 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6960434) -> Close x 1 | **Leave Open** x 3

Overall: Close - 1 | Leave Open - 5

This question has not seen a single validated review since then. 8 reviews were invalidated, 4 due to vote aging (I suppose) and 4 due to the question being closed before being reviewed in the queue.
It also went through the reopen queue many times:

- [05 Feb 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3985355) -> Reopen x 0 | **Leave Closed** x 3
- [18 Oct 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/9895128) -> Reopen x 0 | **Leave Closed** x 3
- [23 Oct 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/9951353) -> Reopen x 0 | **Leave Closed** x 3
- [30 Nov 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/10390443) -> Reopen x 0 | **Leave Closed** x 3
- [23 May 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12444820) -> Reopen x 0 | **Leave Closed** x 3
- [03 Jul 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12890444) -> Reopen x 0 | **Leave Closed** x 3
- [13 Jul 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12995740) -> **Reopen** x 3 | Leave Closed x 2
- [12 Aug 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/13320851) -> Reopen x 0 | **Leave Closed** x 3
- [15 Aug 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/13333933) -> Reopen x 0 | **Leave Closed** x 3
- [16 Aug 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/13346544) -> Reopen x 0 | **Leave Closed** x 3
- [17 Aug 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/13358948) -> Reopen x 0 | **Leave Closed** x 3

Overall: Reopen - 1 | Leave Closed - 10 (7 without the Meta effect from this post)

---

> I am trying to understand what type of problems require Node.js as opposed to any of the mighty kings out there [...]
>
> I understand that it really depends on the expertise one has on a language [...]
>
> When to use [Node.JS] and what type of problems is it particularly suited for?

Not only is this opinion-based as it requires tying real-life programming problems to programming concepts (think *"I need a slideshow"* to *"Let's go for event-based asynchronous programming"*), it's also incredibly broad as per the amount of types of "problems" there exists.
The next sentence of the question nails it perfectly: **it depends on your own expertise**.

---

Most answers cover a couple specific use-cases for which the users feel Node.JS is great or a few reasons for why to use / avoid Node.JS or JavaScript. As such, they are fairly poor.

---

Given that, like all famous questions, it won't stay closed for very long (and I expect the Meta effect to worsen the situation in that regard):

#### How can we fix this question?

Comment: TL; DR; Closing and deletion for asking about opinions. I know that was actually bumped by @Tunaki in the chat room.

Comment: Many famous questions are closed and remain closed.

Comment: Does anything really need to be done with this question? If it stays closed, great. If it doesn't... well, it would probably gravitate towards being closed again. It provides useful information, so no need to delete it. Seems to me like it's fine as it is.

Comment: @hichris123 At this point, the question is "OK" because it's closed. The issue is it could be reopened at any point, where new (bad) answers are added... when it was reopened just recently, it received a new answer within a day or so. The question *shouldn't* exist here, but it does and it meets some threshold for "good content", so this is mostly an attempt to get the best of both worlds: retaining the "good content" while preventing it from getting new activity.

Comment: At first glance, the question seems to comply with [the guidelines for "subjective" questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), making it perfectly acceptable. Granted I'm not a topic expert here, so I'm not entirely certain, but my gut instinct is that the usual cadre of close-voters are applying the rules too literally again. This would explain why community team members have twice stepped in to reopen it.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah, Andrew Barber tends to apply the rules too literally.

Comment: Anyone can tell how many deleted answers this have?

Comment: @Braiam:  [How to decide when to use Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062614/how-to-decide-when-to-use-node-js) currently has 11 deleted answers.

Comment: @kjhughes yikes, leaving it open is definitively not an option.

Comment: This question completed no less then 7(!) reopen queue reviews with 3x Leave closed, and 1 with 3x reopen and 2x leave closed.

Comment: @Magisch And there's already another 3 re-open votes on it now.

Comment: With a bit more specific requirements this question could be a great one for softwarerecommendations.stackexchange or maybe it could even be part of Documentation.

Comment: And why was this reopened? It isn't a good question by any metric and it has shown itself to be a lighting rod for crap answers, the very same reason of why we close them... *sighs*

Comment: @Braiam Came here to ask the same thing. Thrown a CV on it, but if closed, it will likely get reopened again.

Comment: Oil, gas, matches, tar, feathers, you name it, that question needs some of it.

Comment: If that question isn't closed and deleted, ya might as well be consistent and give up on GoDaddy burn.

Comment: Close it, give it a historical lock, and move on.

Comment: No, @Braiam, we do not close a question because it is getting poor answers. Getting poor answers may be a symptom of a poor question, but it is also a sign of popularity. Any popular question is going to have a number of poor answers; most popular questions are not closeable.

Comment: @hichris123 err... we close questions because the kind of answers they attract. "Primarily opinion based" says "**answers to this question** will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." So, we close the questions because they attract bad answers, and what better guidance than a cesspool of answers to convince close voters to close it? (I admit, that for some questions we simply know that it will attract bad answers, but again, is because the answers they attract that we close them)

Comment: @hichris123 imo Braiam is correct. We do not focus on the quality of answers as they trickle in, but of the types of answers that the question is likely to generate. What the question is trying to do. Is it swinging for the fences of Quora dot com. So  it gets back to the question itself. And in my opinion, as fun as the Q is, that question is crap. It is wide open too POB it steers toward mayhem.

Comment: FWIW I think it's a very good question, like many other questions that "aren't fit for SO" and yet somehow gather *thousands* of upvotes. Well-voiced opinions have the potential to save you a lot of time - consider "when should I go with raw SQL queries vs. using ORM?". People could show their field experience with both approaches, maybe share some horror stories, and let you help decide early to avoid making the same mistakes they did. I myself found on several occasions questions in form of "which library do I use"? And boy I was grateful for staying off the mods' grid.

Comment: Obviously the community is divided over this question. I want a running count of how often it was opened and closed. Regarding what can be done: I believe in rationality. If a question is good one can define criteria and formulate rules that leave the good questions open and the bad questions closed.

Comment: @Kyll You're right. The information about closing and reopening votes is stored. I just wanted to say it would be interesting to display how often this question has gone through the close/reopen cycle by now. That information is not directly available, but all information leading to it is available.

Comment: @tri Whaddya mean it's not directly available? It's in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5062614/revisions), and the question hasn't been deleted, so anyone can see it.

Comment: @CodyGray So six close/reopen cycles so far. With not directly I meant, the total number is not printed as such. But I just had to count the closes so that is fairly direct. I apologize.

Comment: @Braiam, if some answers are problematic, then the community will downvote them. That's why we have downvoting, unlike Facebook. If you want to kill the question because some answers are low quality, that's just throwing the entire barrel away because of a few rotten apples.

Comment: @DanDascalescu so, lets cuddle the bad question that produce crap tons of answers just because? NO. Deal with the problem that generates the problem, the question.

Comment: @Braiam: Truly interesting questions are always bound to also produce what you'd call crap answers. Try to imagine that most SE users are *not* like you. Here's what *the community* has valued: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124850/unofficial-stack-overflow-deleted-question-archive-now-available/222931), [2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/73226/set-up-an-archive-for-legendary-deleted-questions), [3](http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions-top100.html).

Comment: @DanDascalescu I'm not saying that they aren't interesting, I love interesting questions, but questions that can be interesting could also not work well with SE Q&A format, and attract crap.

Comment: FWIW I think the question is a good one and one worth asking, and there are some good answers, but the part that matters is that I think the content *does not belong on stackoverflow.com*. Quora (or maybe some site on the SE network aside from Stack Overflow... they keep adding new ones!) is the kind of place to have this discussion (because that's really what this Q&A is; a discussion between veterans on when to use Node.js).

Comment: @TylerH: splitting SE into a myriad of sites is counter-productive. The community does a so-so job at migrating questions, and every day I run into dupes spread across AkUbuntu, Unix&Linux, SuperUser, SO, Programmers, or WebMasters. Android questions have a much better chance at getting good answers on SO, and so do Wordpress ones etc.

Comment: It's amazing that SO allow such board questions as long as it makes traffic

Comment: Next time Kyll, lets just delete this quietly. If nobody shouts after a week, we did the right thing.

Comment: Reopen it since the selected answer is technically incorrect and converts StackOverflow in a platform to disseminate incorrect information.

Comment: @arboreal84 how about we delete it so misinformation isn't disseminated?

Comment: @Braiam That could be one solution. However seems a bit disrespectful to the people who answered the question correctly. There are many correct answers in that post.

Comment: @arboreal84 why would it be disrespectful? If they cared about their content they would have downvoted the other answers and vote to close the question *out of respect for themselves*, since they were tricked into answering such bike-shed question.

Comment: Deleting the question itself would be disrespectful to the people that answered correctly. Deleting the wrong answers may be a bit more acceptable but **ideally** it would be just better that people doesn't upvote claims they can't verify.

Comment: Sorry, what is there to fix about it? Honestly this whole thread is really dedicated and serious, but for many, questions like that are very helpful. It might be a fugazi, but it's also not. For many this might be the entry point for SO in this topic, and they will find that they can find answers for their more "specific" questions, that you guys would probably appreciate more. But I think these questions fit in perfectly, this helps SO's community grow. This is important for the health of this forum, which could see some sunlight honestly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems the consensus (both of the community and of the moderators) is that the post should be locked.

## ... so it has been locked.

The lock will remain permanently.

Comment: This is kinda sad. The answers to the question obviously need some improvement; now, the answers will never be revised again. Why does this question need to be locked? What problem does it solve? And do the benefits outweigh the cost of no revisions?

Comment: @hichris123 Why? Because it's not an appropriate question for this site. What problem does it solve? Continuing to leave it in a live state is a distraction from what this site aims to be and sends the wrong message on the kind of content that belongs on the site. Do the benefits outweigh the cost? Yes, the 'cost' of no revisions is not really a cost at all since there are a million and one blog posts out there that talk about the pros & cons of Node.js already. We don't need one more on Stack&nbsp;Overflow.

Comment: Is it really a distraction, @TylerH? I suggest you read [Cody's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332386/what-should-be-done-about-this-specific-famous-controversial-question-asking-whe#comment383150_332386) up above, and [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332671). The cost of no revisions means links can rot, information can become obsolete. Is that really what we want for Stack Overflow?

Comment: @TylerH What problem it solves? It explains what one of the tools we use is for. If that's not a desirable question on our site, that is essentially saying that either no one knows what the tools are for, or that programmers should figure out how to use their tools on their own for whatever reason. And I second hichris123 that at first we say that subjective questions are fine and dandy if they follow certain rules, and when it comes to actual questions, the attitude is "ah, it's more difficult to direct the answers in the right direction than usual, so to heck with such questions".

Comment: @hichris123 No, we want to delete old, problematic, off-topic content if possible, or at least lock it with a notice saying "this content is not a good example for the site". The last edited dates and last activity associated with each post should clue users into the age of the content.

Comment: @TylerH So since when did we decide that age makes the content not useful? Last time I looked, node.js is still here and its purpose didn't change. The question is neither off-topic, nor outdated, and it's only problematic in the sense that subjective questions are more difficult (but absolutely possible) to moderate. But yeah, locking it is, of course, much easier because it doesn't involve any efforts beyond clicking the button.

Comment: @Malcolm When content is age-specific. A question on how to layout elements on a page w/ an answer saying to use table based layouts in CSS might have been seen as good in 2009 but it would be downvoted into oblivion (hopefully) today. But, you miss the point. The word "old" was just one of several descriptors, and was not even chief among them. The fact of the matter is that the NodeJS question is objectively off-topic and also attracts crappy/spammy answers when left alone. If you think it should be considered on-topic, you need to petition the site to change its rules about topicality.

Comment: @TylerH "Question is objectively off-topic" - repeating this once more still doesn't explain why you think that's the case. "attracts crappy answers" - it does as any subjective question does. And if we declared that we welcome subjective questions, we need to figure out how to make sure they have good answers instead of coping out by nuking them. There have been pretty good suggestions in other answers and comments to them. "answer saying to use table based layouts in CSS" - so why does that make the question wrong? Do a bounty, there's even a special reason, "current answers are outdated".

Comment: @Malcolm If you observe the closure options for questions and peruse the relevant topics in the Help Center, there's no shortage of words spent on describing how opinion-based questions, while good questions to ask, are not on-topic at Stack Overflow (because SO is not Quora). It is not because the answers are outdated that the question should be closed/locked; it's because it is off-topic.

Comment: @TylerH I'm aware of those reasons. You need to show why they apply here. And also I'm aware that there are guidelines which indicate what a good subjective question is, which this question adheres to as [it has been shown](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332671/45668).

Comment: @Malcolm I'm sorry, I thought it was obvious in the question "When should I use NodeJS" how it was an opinion-based question. First of all, it implies that NodeJS is the tool to use over competitors, which, itself, is an opinion. Second, since it is a framework, there's never a need to use it; you can always use vanilla JavaScript to accomplish the same thing. When *should* you use it? Well, it depends. The fact that the answer will start with "it depends" makes it opinionated.

Comment: @Malcolm Also I wouldn't recommend citing a -3 answer that disagrees with the +40s question and +50s answer (among other answers, including the moderator response) as an exemplary defense.

Comment: @TylerH Time to [move to the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121385/discussion-between-malcolm-and-tylerh), I believe.

Comment: Consensus is not a good reason. No more so than the old adage about "if all your friends jumped off a cliff...".  This answer doesn't provide a reason or justification - it merely describes the behaviour - that a bunch of people wanted the question locked.  Behaviour that some people still see as problematic and are seeking justification for.  This is an empty non-answer.

Answer (score 56):

This question and its answers are Too Broad *and* Primarily Opinion-Based. The question was off-topic when it was asked, and it is off-topic now. At the very least, it should remain closed. When the question remains open, it gathers new crappy answers, even in 2016.

At best it should be given a Historical Lock. My mod flag for this was declined with the reason being "that would prevent upkeep of links". To be honest, the links will still be captured by the Internet Archive if people really want to read them.

Alternatively, there really should be a way to lock a question without locking the answers from being edited. I'm positive I've seen that before...

Comment: There's the [wiki-lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182566/this-lock-notice-is-partly-misleading/182572#182572), but I think that only allows the accepted answer to be edited.  (And it doesn't seem to be documented elsewhere, so I'm not sure if it's still available.)

Comment: Er, since historical locks *always* prevent upkeep of links. If that's a valid reason to deny that flag, why do we have the flag? (I realize I'm preaching to the choir since you're the one who flagged the question, but I do wonder if there's something about this question in particular that led someone to deny your flag.)

Comment: @KyleStrand mods can decline flags if they don't believe the question belongs to the site and should not be locked either.

Comment: @Braiam I don't understand why the flag was declined *for this particular question*, though. Are the links particularly susceptible to link-rot, or particularly important to the question and answer? The given reason for denying the flag, as stated, can't be valid *on its own*, because it would completely invalidate *any* use of the historical-lock. Also, I don't understand your statement: how could a question not belong on the site, but also deserve to be kept unlocked?

Comment: @KyleStrand simple: because lock prevent user moderation, and this question needs user moderation. What kind of moderation is up to debate, but locking it prevents it.

Comment: @Braiam ....but why would a locked question require moderation? Locking freezes the question, so....doesn't that obviate moderation?

Comment: @KyleStrand nothing ever is a perfect state... moderating guides stuff towards its perfect state.

Comment: In my opinion the perfect state of that question is deleted :-)

Comment: Why didn't you say that in your answer :(

Comment: @Braiam Because there's an established precedent for retaining popular content whether it belongs on the site or not, so there's no use in muddling my answer with that request/position :-)

Comment: Which is why I reject anything that goes against content curation: creates a bad precedence that later gets used for *anything*, but what it was meant to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions

Comment: @raheelshan The question has been protected for over four years already.

Comment: The highest voted answer on the question was the first answer posted, which was 10 minutes after being posted. The end of the answer stated "***I look forward to reading other answers here, this is a fantastic question.***" I think that comment was probably the reason it wasn't closed and deleted before it got popular.

Comment: @4castle I love that you use the world "popular", and I feel that this whole situation sends the signal of "become popular, rules stop applying to you once you do", which isn't optimal in any system.

Answer (score 33):

The problem with *"X vs Y"* or *"When to use X"* questions is that all they do is attract opinions, and useless ones at that.

An answer stating *"We built some service using X, and it was [way nicer|much faster|quicker to develop] than Y"* is totally and utterly useless. In the first place, because nobody can verify it (they may be lying, or advertising, although I'm not certain whether that's a difference). Secondly, because we don't know exactly how and on what aspects they evaluated the choices (they may have simply implemented Y wrong, or chosen Y as wrong tool for the job to begin with). Thirdly, and most importantly, because their scenario may very well not apply to your, the reader's, scenario (**you** may be misinformed trying to learn about either X or Y to solve your particular problem).

Everything that *"X vs Y"* or *"When to use X"* questions explain to you is that you, the reader, lack experience. You **cannot** fill this experience gap by substituting that void with someone else's one-time experience.

You need to thoroughly determine your requirements. List them, turn them around, re-evaluate them, discuss them with a peer or two until it is very, very clear what problem exactly you're trying to solve.

**Then**, and only then you can start listing tools, libraries, frameworks and whatnot that fulfill those requirements. Go read the documentation, specifications, whitepapers, testimonials, blogs, benchmarks and everything else you can find that can help you decide what tool X (or Y, for that matter) does and how it can help you.

If your requirement is *"I need a light-weight, single-threaded JavaScript-interpreting event-driven web server"* then sure! Go ahead and give Node.JS a try. Build a POC, benchmark it against your go-to web platform and evaluate the choice for your next greenfield project.

But **don't** say *"I know, I'll use Node.JS for my next project!"* because some guy from Texas wrote a three-paragraph answer on Stack Overflow, saying *"Ya know, I used it once and I kinda liked it!"*. And sure as hell don't give him a thousand upvotes, you zealots.

So, in short: questions like these don't fit the Q&A format of Stack Overflow, because its answers don't teach you anything that you can rely on. They aren't verifyable. They're opinions.

Comment: What you propose to do with it?

Comment: I'm no mod, @Braiam, but I'd go for a closure as opinion-based and a historical lock. I don't like deleting questions that've been viewed by many, however useful or not they are.

Comment: What if I told you that everything in those answers is just below SO in the search results, just better? Would you change your opinion?

Comment: @Braiam I don't understand what you mean by that. I would like to remark though that _"When to use X"_ is an utterly unhelpful web search query that will yield opinion-based answers, whether on Stack Overflow or not.

Comment: "I don't like **deleting questions** that've been viewed by many", I'm telling you that even if we deleted it, the information would be still available. Basically "information before deletion = information after deletion" with the cherry that we don't have to spend our limited resources moderating it.

Comment: I disagree that the answers are useless. In fact, I find them more useful since they really help guide my thinking on the subject and further exploration. They are not a good fit for the site, and they don't belong, but they are _not_ useless, that is a misconception. I'd say the issue is that they they are too nuanced for SO's rigid structure.

Comment: @ArtB if by "nuanced" you mean "opinion-based" and by"rigid" you mean "factual", I can agree.

Comment: Yes I do. The best answer to good a question is more questions to make you question the assumptions behind your original question. SO is not a place for that, but that does not mean the question itself are valuable. My only point is not all that we discourage is without value.

Comment: @ArtB but don't get me wrong. I'm all for reading or hearing about other people's experiences in regard to everything about software development. It's just that Stack Overflow is not the place for sharing such experiences. It does not fit the Q&A format very well. Edit: heh, timing.

Comment: I agree @ArtB, sadly, as you point out SE isn't a good platform for that, and I doubt it even exist. The thing is that while we could encourage brain teasers, the lowest common denominator imposes itself and ruins it for the rest of us... which is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: @Braiam that kind of platform _could_ exist, but it would be against the spirit of SE: you'd have to be more worried about false positives than false negatives. Questions & answers would have to prove themselves worthy of not getting deleted instead of the reverse now. I point this out to say that rejecting certains kinds of content is part of the compromises we make to keep the community open to new comers.

Comment: @ArtB If you read my comment again I say that it isn't SE, nor it could exist. BTW, we have +11 million questions, so cut me some slack, if we discuss each one that is worthy we wouldn't delete anything ever...

Comment: That platform exists, and it's called Quora, and we have [a lot to learn from it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/what-can-we-learn-from-quora), mainly to not be such blind rule followers.

Comment: That post has 2205 upvotes, and 1485 stars. Obviously, a LOT of people found it useful, whether or not it adhere's to SO's strict rigid posting guidelines. It is among the top results for Google searches like "node.js use cases" and "node.js usage". Fact is, the community has shown that they found it useful, and I'm sure it has driven countless amounts of web traffic to SO. You are suggesting that we should delete a post that has survived 5 years of moderation activity and benefited thousands of people & the site as a whole, because it doesn't fit the Q&A format?

Comment: @user5359531 nowhere am I recommending deletion.

Comment: @user5359531 if you by "useful" mean "popular", then yes, it's popular

Comment: @Braiam, no I do not mean 'popular'. If you mouse over the 'up vote' button, you should see that it displays the text 'This question [...] is useful'. At the time of my comment, the post had 2205 upvotes. Thus, 2205 people found it to be useful.

Comment: I imagine 'upvoting' a question like this is akin to saying 'I wanna know too!' more than it is 'I found this useful' - either way, the problem wasn't the question IMO, it's the lack of objective answers. What I'd wanna see as a newbie to Node is the fact that my code was gonna be interpreted by the same engine that powers 40% of the world's browsers, and I could therefore write code that runs in both places. Or the ecosystem around React or other popular frameworks. Or how it can be useful even as a front-end build pipeline outside of the server. Specific use cases other stacks lack.

Comment: @user5359531 ["A question being open indicates it's a good fit for Stack Overflow, **a question having votes indicates it's a popular (or good) question.**"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251536/792066) I recommend also read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality. Basically, on these kind of questions, whatever the tooltips says has no bearing with what it actually implies.

Comment: @Braiam SO guidelines dictate that users should upvote useful questions. We should disregard SO guidelines in order to delete a question that you think violates SO guidelines, despite the fact that the questions' utility was demonstrated by users following SO guidelines? Seems like you are cherry-picking which guidelines should be followed, and which should be ignored. If we are delving into subjectivity, then I think it would be a mistake to delete a question that so many people have found useful.

Comment: @user5359531 right back at ya: SO guidelines dictates that users should ["avoid asking subjective questions"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), should we disregards SO guidelines in order to keep a question that **do violate** SO guidelines?

Comment: I already answered that question: "If we are delving into subjectivity, then I think it would be a mistake to delete a question that so many people have found useful."

Comment: @user5359531 s/useful/entertaining/ remember that distinction!

Comment: "give him a thousand upvotes, you zealots."  By him, CodeCaster means himself on this particular question. +1

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a slightly different stance here and say that this question is a lot better than it was made out to be. Going along with [Cody's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332386/what-should-be-done-about-this-specific-famous-controversial-question-asking-whe#comment383150_332386), this seems to be a decent subjective question. Many moons ago, guidelines were set out for good subjective questions in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/):

> ### Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions
>
> 1. **Great subjective questions inspire answers that explain "why" and "how".**
> 2. **Great subjective questions tend to have long, not short, answers**.
> 3. **Great subjective questions have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.**
> 4. **Great subjective questions invite sharing experiences over opinions**.
> 5. **Great subjective questions insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references**.
> 6. **Great subjective questions are more than just mindless social fun**.

Now, let's take a look at these. #1 applies here for sure: it asks about how and why to decide to use Node.js. #3, #4, and #6 all apply here. The question doesn't necessarily specify that answers should be backed up by references (#5), but it seems that most answers did that anyway. And #2 seems to generally apply here -- some answers are probably a bit shorter than they should be, but overall, the answers are not just "Use Node for Y because."

Overall, this seems to follow the guidelines set out in Good Subjective, Bad Subjective. However, some of the answers are not that great in these terms -- they answer the question, but lack clarity or references or explanation.

So what should be done here? *Cleanup the answers.* The question seems fine overall, but the answers are lacking. If the answers can be made to fit into these guidelines, we'd have a useful reference that follows site guidelines. While historically locking this question would theoretically work, it prevents any cleanup or revision of answers. Besides, historical locks [really aren't the best tool for most jobs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257605/we-could-use-better-management-of-popular-but-bad-questions/257653#257653).

Overall, I'd recommend:

1. Unlocking the question. Quite obviously, the answers need revisions, and those can't be done with the question locked. Historically locking this question is not the best path.
2. Possibly reopening the question. It appears to fit into the subjective guidelines, and as long as the answers are cleaned up and maintained, it is a useful guide. New answers, drawing upon experience and backing up their statements with facts/references, would be a good addition to this question.

Comment: "Possibly reopening the question" there was a reopen-close cycle, that the question was open, promptly got a bad answer that got flagged and deleted. I doubt moderators and users alike would be willing to cuddle a problem question, instead of dealing with it.

Comment: @Braiam On Programmers.SE I've seen a lot that people claim to be following these guidelines, but in reality a lot of good subjective questions still get closed. I even [wrote about it on Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6659/32689). That's the same case here. If the question respects the guidelines, then this is not a problem question. It's just lazy people who pick the easiest solution for preventing bad answers from being written instead of trying to do something that requires certain effort.

Comment: Subjective questions can be great but they are not great for Stack Overflow. This is not Quora, this is not a blog, there's not even a programming problem posed in that Node.js question to begin with. It's just an expose on what NodeJS is good for. Arguing that it is good or useful content *in general* can be forgiven, but arguing that it belongs on the site is demonstrably false.

Comment: Taken directly from Robert's [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), @TylerH: "**We never claimed that subjective questions were horrible abominations that should never be asked.** ... If we can avoid conversations that are -- and this is the really tricky part -- *too subjective*, we can maintain the ideals of great Q&A in the face of completely subjective topics."

Comment: @hichris123 Yes, there's always something subjective in a human response or solution to a problem because we are creative and we often don't mind a few nanoseconds of difference in how fast our code is or whether it is 10 lines or 11 lines, at least for the purpose of the question. And no one has said this NodeJS question is a horrible abomination that should never be asked, we've only said that it should not be asked *on Stack Overflow*, because it's **primarily opinion-based**.

Comment: At this point, you're just wasting my time @TylerH. Have you read the blog post? That is not what it is talking about.

Comment: @hichris123 I read the blog post long ago when it was posted. I didn't read it just now, but that's OK because I wasn't referencing it; I was referencing *your* comment. To be frank, you're wasting *my* time because the community and, importantly, the entire moderator staff has agreed the question is off-topic and should remain locked forever. Why continue to act like your stance is still correct?

Comment: Obviously the entire community doesn't agree @Tyler. But this discussion is quickly going nowhere. A discussion is never a waste of time unless both sides are talking past each other; unfortunately, that seems to be occurring now.

Comment: @hichris123 It wasn't really a discussion; your answer was asking a question (theoretically) to seek understanding and I was simply commenting attempting to explain the answer to your question. You have just not been inclined to accept the answers.

Comment: I will, of course, accept what the outcome of this is, @Tyler. What else can I do? I'm not a moderator, I can't unlock the question. What I can do is disagree. I disagree that this question should be locked. I disagree that this question is a "bad subjective" question ("experience" in the question is the key). And I think quite a few people agree with me there. Is it worth the time to fix and to improve? Perhaps, perhaps not. But there's no reason to paint this question with such a broad stroke -- there are redeeming qualities to it.

Comment: Sorry, what is there to fix about it? Honestly this whole thread is really dedicated and serious, but for many, questions like that are very helpful. It might be a fugazi, but it's also not. For many this might be the entry point for SO in this topic, and they will find that they can find answers for their more "specific" questions, that you guys would probably appreciate more. But I think these questions fit in perfectly, this helps SO's community grow. This is important for the health of this forum, which could see some sunlight honestly.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly oppose those who say that the questions like "When to use X and what type of problems is it particularly suited for?" are not answerable. Programming languages are tools. Any real tool has a specific purpose, advantages and disadvantages, and an area where it's commonly used. All of that constitutes a perfectly valid and helpful answer.

Also I believe that many **confuse two kinds of questions** here: *what technology should be used for a specific problem* and *what X is designed to deal with*. The first one obviously attracts answers with opinions because usually there are much more than just one tool to solve the problem. The second one shouldn't because frameworks and languages are designed with some specific goals in mind, and those goals will be the answer.

Experience has nothing to do with finding the answer. You don't need to have experience to know that an axe is designed to chop down trees. Of course, you can use it on nails, but no one in the right mind will say that it's the purpose of the axe and what it's usually used for. That's the same thing here. It may be difficult to say which language to use if I need to write a cross-platform app (first kind of questions), but if someone asks me about the advantages of, say, Java (second kind of questions), I will definitely mention cross-platform applications because that's what it was designed for.

It kind of even saddens me to see that we try to ban questions which ask about the purpose of the tools we use. I immediately imagine some guy which gets the aforementioned axe, doesn't know what to do with it, and starts to gain his experience by hammering down nails, chopping meat, prying open doors, and doing God knows what until he discovers that it's actually convenient to chop down trees with it. And while it does other things, it is quite mediocre at that and it's actually not something it is supposed to be used for. Is that really what our profession is about?

Comment: @Kyll It will, and that's precisely what I dislike. I know I'm in minority here, you don't need to tell me that. Explain why you disagree instead.

Comment: Good point, but I think these answers would still be too broad. A programming language is not as simple as an axe :). You could write a book about what Java is for. Maybe a better question would be asking the purpose of specific language features. E.g. _"Why is Java compiled to bytecode and run in a JVM?"_ is better than _"What is Java for?"_

Comment: @DanielDarabos I used Java just as an example, the question is about tools in general. Even with Java, in my opinion, it could probably summarized as something pretty concise. There is more than one reasonable general application of Java, but they are not endless. And for frameworks or libraries the questions will be much narrower.

Comment: All questions are answerable, not all questions are answerable within SE format, and that's a good thing.

Comment: @Braiam I used the word "answerable" in the same sense as in the [site help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). I think that's fairly obvious.

Comment: It's interesting that you linked the "asking" page instead of the answering one http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Braiam Because it mentions the term right in the first sentences. Could you get to the point instead of posting evasive comments?

Comment: I agree with @Malcom. It is completely possible to give a simple, factual answer to a question like "What should this programming language be used for?", and as can be seen by the post in question here about Node.js, a lot of people can find those answers to be helpful. Whether that makes a good SO question is a separate matter.

Comment: Ridiculous analogies never make sense. Classes aren't cars, and web servers aren't axes.

Comment: @CodeCaster I use the analogies to illustrate a point. Calling the analogies ridiculous doesn't invalidate the point. Nice straw man attempt though.

Comment: An axe is a tool that can be used for one and only one purpose, which Node.JS is absolutely not. It beats the entire purpose of the analogy. Furthermore, the top-voted answer explains the ridiculousness that I tried to address in my answer: two-thirds of that answer state that you can use Node for long-polling, so you can create chat websites. The other third explains that you can reuse code because you'll have JS running on both server and client. Those two statements are not unique to Node.JS, by far not the only reasons to choose to utilize it and all in all not worth 1375 upvotes.

Comment: @CodeCaster OK, so you think the top-voted answer is poor and doesn't address the question well. What does this have to do with my point? Another straw man. By the way, axes have more than one purpose too, but I don't want to discuss the nuances of the lumberjack profession because it's irrelevant.

Comment: It proves _my_ point: it's a useless question for the "ask a question, get a definitive answer" format of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't see how it proves your point. If a good answer hasn't been written, it doesn't mean it can't be written.

Comment: It hasn't been in five years, and it won't be, because it won't fit in the answer box.

Comment: @CodeCaster I see some pretty good answers there. Moreover, I would argue that if you can't say what the library is for in a few paragraphs, it is probably a poor library because no one can figure out what problems it is supposed to solve.

Comment: Just want to point out that the [Node.js info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info) certainly strives to outline the types of problems that Node.js is suited to solve.

Comment: @DavidRR Exactly, information like that would be a perfect answer to the question. So I absolutely disagree that such questions can't be answered.

Comment: @DavidRR then... why are we trying to be the node.js info page?

Comment: @Braiam Because we may not have a tag wiki, or the description in there may be absent, or the description may be short and unhelpful. We are discussing the general case here. Even if this particular question has a good wiki description, that doesn't mean that it will always be the case.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, the tag info page should be the first stop to get an introduction to the purpose and scope of a technology. Unfortunately, it seems, the tag info pages [aren't widely used](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323800/1497596). I seem to be one of the few who discovered their value early on. I also feel that to a degree the purpose of the tag info pages overlaps with the new Documentation aspect of SO. I'm disappointed that the tag info pages aren't getting more love.

Comment: @Malcolm Do we agree that the tag info page is an ideal place to record the purpose and scope of a technology? If so, how do we the SO community see to it that such questions are addressed in the tag info pages?

Comment: @DavidRR It's fine by me if the information goes there, the only problem is that I don't see how someone would request the information to be updated. With the question it's easy: anyone can ask a question, anyone can answer, the best answers rise to the top, and the deal is done. With the tag, however, I don't even see what the right way to initiate the process is.

Comment: @Malcolm Documentation has a feature that allows its readers to make "improvement requests." I'd very much like to see the tag info pages offer something similar. (Providing this would be one step in the direction of giving tag info pages more of the love that they deserve.)

Comment: @DavidRR That would be a great solution, maybe we should propose something like that.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is rather simplistic: the same needs to be done here as with the book listing question as it follows the same patterns.

- An off-topic question - or similarly: a question where the off-topicness is so heavily disputed that it results in moderation wars
- massive amount of upvotes
- many stars
- many cycles of moderation actions over the course of several years.

[What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)

Apparently: locking it is the end-station.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that off-topic questions of such significance need to be locked. The question is whether it is off-topic and non-salvageable, and while it is apparently obvious to you, I disagree that it's the case.

Comment: @malcolm You're right, I edited a bit to make that less black & white

Comment: If it's heavily disputed, then a decision needs to be made, I don't see why the dispute should automatically be resolved in favor of closing. This is precisely the question where it should happen.

Comment: I did, but I prefer to always explain why. Downvotes need a rationale on meta too.

Comment: @malcolm Oh whoops, the total score threw me off. In my defence, but a weak attempt at it, I said *locking* and not specifically closing. The (history) lock is a tool to put a stop to unending disputes and stops further opinionated moderation actions. It also stops further voting on content, but I think the existing content already got a disproportionate amount of votes to really have any meaning anymore. Me personally I'm fine with it being applied as the best of a bad situation.

Comment: Well, I should've said locking in my comment. It's not the same as closing, but it still prevents new answers from being written and shows that this type of questions is unwelcome on the site. However, I think that if we stop discussing what the tools are used to be for, that's a really grim outcome because that is essentially admitting that we don't know how to use our tools.

Comment: @malcolm I actually don't disagree. Question is: how do you hold a discussion about such a subject that does not mirror the kind of disagreement that you see happening in the questions that the discussion will be about? seeing this meta question... it yet again goes from "leave it be!" to "Pour gasoline and light a flame!"

Comment: Yeah, it's much simpler to burn such questions than to make the effort to turn them into something useful, that's why the decision seems to have been made on the side of locking. But at least I've put my two cents to ease my conscience because I think we're doing a disservice to our craft by making such a ruling. That's my personal opinion.

Comment: @Gimby that is probably because we have tested *by fire* (["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/213575)), that such questions simply don't work here.

Comment: @braiam its a nice read for sure and a nice bit of history. But what exactly it is an explanation for in this context, I'm afraid I don't really know ;) The defunct site was for questions that were most definitely off-topic.

Comment: @Gimby we tried to make a site for questions with a more subjective-y nature, the question we are talking about was one of the reasons why it was created, and it didn't work out.

Comment: @Braiam well that's just it - the discussion here is *if* the question would belong on such a site or not. The fact that the question gets moderated into all possible directions seems to indicate that is not as clear-cut as one might want to believe. And then when it is not clear-cut and a question enters a close/reopen/delete/lock/reopen kind of loop, what then?

Comment: @Gimby content curation has to win out. The site is based upon it, it feels quite depressing that it gets thrown out the window in these discussions.

Answer (score -2):

A question with that many page views and upvotes obviously hints that it's a question many devs have on their mind. Closing it as off-topic because it incites opinion and attracts crappy answers is a cop-out, IMO.

Three ideas:

1. Aggressively prune poor answers. Maybe there could be a 'controversial' flag applied to Qs that seem to be attracting low quality answers, which hides answers completely that get a smaller number of downvotes, instead of just greying them out. Or, deduct points at a higher rate. The idea being to disincentive piggybacking off popular questions if you're going to just add noise.
2. Coming from the opposite angle, how about an 'expert' flag, that limits responses to users that are within the top x% of a question's parent tag/technology. For this, the tag would obviously be node.js or Javascript. Say, for argument's sake, the top 10% in either category. An obvious argument might be that it has the potential to introduce bias (i.e. if a user is top 10% Javascript, presumably they have an affinity for Javascript and might think Node.js is great), but combined with downvoting this might have a levelling effect. In any case - it should yield more accurate answers.
3. Employ community curators, who can be trusted to assemble third-party arguments on both sides, for and against a particular tech choice, paradigm or technique.

In any case, simply closing the question and leaving up a bunch of crappy answers doesn't help the 300,000 people who stumbled upon it for a reason - nor does it really help move forward arguments for and against. It risks leaving later viewers more confused, or frustrated that a perfectly legit question (to their mind) has been closed by a community who seemingly thinks it's too dumb of a question to ask.

Comment: This will not work in the long term, we have better things to do than cuddling poor fit questions.

Comment: Who's 'we'? My suggestion is applying tags that improve the scoring algorithm on open-ended Qs and do some of the work for you. Clearly the viewer numbers show that you've got a captive audience - IMO it needs honing, not pruning. Open-ended but popular Qs aren't going to go away.

Comment: So, you are saying that the site should trove only for entertainment and nothing else? We already have some of that, they are called Yahoo Answers and Quora. We don't need SE to become like that.

Comment: Obviously not. I'm saying that vast swaths of people want to know the answer - that there's a _demand_ for an answer. You can either pretend there isn't and say SO only caters to intermediate and above devs who wouldn't ask such a naive and newbie Q, or, you can recognise that those questions will keep coming and find a better way to deal with them.

Comment: And who says we should bow to their demands? They can demand whatever they want, we don't have to be their supply. SE is popular because is good, is good because of its model, questions like that doesn't fit the model. Recommended read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/

Comment: You're not beholden to anything. I'm offering you a suggestion. Take it or leave it. I find SO useful and have helped others by answering their Qs; I'll continue using it either way. But I do think chastising someone who has a perfectly valid question, but lacks the experience to know how to properly express it, is elitist, arrogant and ultimately unhelpful. If there are ways of pruning poorer answers and promoting better ones, it can only serve to help. Surely that's a good thing that's worth exploring? Or are lesser experienced folk not worth your time?

Comment: So, we are going ad hominem? These questions simply don't belong here. In fact, I think the question was well expressed and formulated, but sadly **it is in the wrong place**. From my point of view is like having a Donatello in the main entry of a house: the sculpture can looks as good as it can be, but it's a mayor annoyance for the residents.

Comment: I'm not a mod, so I don't share your frustrations. It's up to SO what it wants to be. I just find it odd that a legit question with 2,000+ upvotes and such a clear demand would be told it has a better home at Yahoo Answers. I'd rather see more objective answers than lock the question and hold it in stasis. All you've done is pissed off a bunch of future visitors who now have guaranteed crappy answers, because you've barred better ones.

Answer (score -4):

> How can we fix this question?

This requires **effort**. If you aren't willing to expend some effort, then my answer will not be of any use. Also, I presume you are worried about the content to be deleted, this answer fix that in a sensible way.

From a cursory glance to the answers, it seems to me that most of them are in the format:

> I used node.js for this *[feature]* that helps me with this *[task]*.

From there you can ask a question that still accepts that kind of answers, but I think such question is still no good for SO, yet it has already been asked [Why The Hell Would I Use Node.js?](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/why-the-hell-would-i-use-node-js), which already has some of the information in the answers *and some more*. It comes up when I search for "nodejs features" and "when to use nodejs", which are more or less the keywords that anyone should need to look this up, and appears just below the question you reference.

One can make a point to contact the author of toptal and fill whatever is missing.

Answer (score -17):

Choosing between technologies is a big thing in the life of a programmer, so such questions are not only popular in a sense of cats and funny memes, but also help people to argue and decide in their real lives. Yet, such questions violate the rules of SO, and the rules are designed to filter out useless texts that can gather attention, entertain but not produce any practical use, they also protect SO and users legally and everywhere else. Now, maybe instead of just thinking "Should it stay or should I close" we start thinking how to help people to choose between technologies and help them to help others to choose. Making a choice is always hard, not fully deterministic, and even after years of practicing some technology you still can get it wrong and could better switch to something else, if you knew it, if you had more facts on your hands. Think of Stackoverflow Comparisons or Stackoverflow Reviews for example. Although this indeed will bring SO into dirty water of debates and competition between players, imagine Google and Microsoft compilers compared, with one of them favored in the end. Simply put, I mean "help to choose" is a special category of questions that might need a special set of rules, but still could benefit very much to all three parties: technology makers (they will know how to improve their weak spots), Stackoverflow (more audience, more views), us mere end users (will help us to choose and let us express our experience and be helpful unto others).

Well, one more point here, people are already up voting the answers that they think help them to make the right choice, does it mean anything, is this the democracy in action or people are just randomly having fun and pollute the question-space?

Comment: I'm not sure that widely expanding the scope of the site is the right approach to the question above.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/ You might also like [Slant](https://www.slant.co/).

Answer (score -19):

In my opinion, the main criteria for whether a question on Stack Overflow is good or not is whether I want to read it and its answers when I'm googling or using Stack Overflow's search for a similar question. In that sense, it passes my test.

My opinion is not law, but I think that's the use-case for almost all users of Stack Overflow. By closing it, all you're saying is that you don't want people to spend anymore time on it. I think people can decide what they want to spend time on. You can save closing topics for things which have value but are creating toxic conversation. And deleting for topics which are just offensive.

I don't understand what use-case you're pushing for that makes you think it should be closed. If the problem is that it shows up in the recently answered questions feeds or something like that, I think there's better solutions.

Comment: _"I like to see this question on Stack Overflow because I like to see the answers to questions I type into Google appear on Stack Overflow"_ doesn't really sound like good reasoning. Whether we should accept certain kinds of questions on Stack Overflow is determined mainly by usability and maintainability of said questions and their answers.

Comment: Don't use quotation marks for paraphrases. I think Bruce Atkinson in the comments of the blog here made most of my points for me. It's a question of whether you're interested in helping people or arguing and creating an insular culture. blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark

Comment: Sorry, I indeed shouldn't have used quotation marks for my interpretation. You shouldn't use a strawman though: questions that attract bad kinds of answers aren't useful for anyone. Denying such questions has nothing to do with not wanting to help people, on the contrary even.

Comment: The case of Bruce's comment explains very well why I'm against such questions: he is very willing to share his experience on an X vs Y question. That's very nice of him and all, but for properly explaining when to use which scripting language depends so much on the task at hand, platform in use and other tools available, that you cannot possibly thoroughly explain all the differences and reasons to choose either. You'd need a couple of blog posts for that, which does not fit the Q&A format of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think most of the real programming problems I encounter are about trade-offs, and getting a variety of experienced opinions in one place is something blog posts do not fulfill. It is extremely helpful to get various people's rundowns on the same general issue as a place to learn industry terms that you can then independently research for more specific answers. Sometimes it is hard to know what to look up, and those general discussions are nice places to learn the high-level details at stake and to learn the basic consensus on issues one wouldn't have been aware of.

Comment: @Wumbo: "*getting a variety of experienced opinions in one place is something blog posts do not fulfill.*" If you read several of them, they can. "*It is extremely helpful to get various people's rundowns on the same general issue*" I'm sure it is helpful. But this sort of question ***is not what we do here.*** It's that simple. We stopped fielding questions like these years ago. You may or may not like or agree with that policy. But it is *our policy* now, and it's unlikely to change.

Comment: The fact that someone voted to *delete* this answer is at least a little bit worrying. Do we have to follow rules so strictly that even entertaining a thought against them is forbidden?